# $K[t]$ is principal

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

Let $K$ a field. A theorem in my course says that $K[t]$ is principal. In particular, every ideal of $K[t]$ is principal. Now, since $\mathbb Q$ is a field, we have that for exemple, there is a $c(t)\in \mathbb Q(t)$ such that $(t^2+1, 2t)=(c(t))$, but how can I find such a $c(t)$ ? What I know is if $g(t)\in(t^2+1,2t)$ then $$g(t)=f(t)(t^2+1)+k(t)2t,$$ 
but I don't find such a $c(t)$.

Comment: Look at the *proof* that K[t] is principal and you'll soon see what's going on :-) The standard proofs are constructive.

Comment: Is there a theorem in your course called the Euclidean Algorithm? If so, you might find it helpful. Also, can you see that $c(t)$ has to divide both $t^2+1$ and $2t$? and can you work out what polynomials divide both of those?

Comment: Use the Euclidean algorithm to find the $\gcd$ of $t^2+1$ and $2t$.

Comment: Make any progress, Rick?

Comment: Sorry to have not answered earlier, and thank you for asking, I appreciate :-) Actually, I have difficulties de compute $\gcd(t^2+1,2t)$. So, $$t^2+1=\frac{1}{2}t\cdot 2t+1$$ and $$2t=1\cdot 2t+0.$$ Therefore $\gcd(t^2+1,2t)=1$. Would it mean that $(t^2+1,2t)=(1)$ ? Just a little question, how could I compute $\gcd(t^2+1,2t)$ in $\mathbb Z[t]$ ? Because in $\mathbb Z[t]$, since $\frac{1}{2}\notin t$ I can't right $t^2+1=\frac{1}{2}t\cdot 2t$ no ?

Comment: Yes, in ${\bf Q}[t]$, $(t^2+1,2t)=(1)$. In ${\bf Z}[t]$, $(t^2+1,2t)$ is not a principal ideal. But still $\gcd(t^2+1,2t)=1$, since the only divisors of $2t$, other than units, are $\pm2$, $\pm t$, and $\pm2t$, and none of these divide $t^2+1$.

Comment: So we can compute a $\gcd$ only in principal ring ? Other question, if $A$ is a UFD ring and $p$ is prime, is $A/(p)$ UFD or never ? What I mean is to check the irreductibility of a polynomial $f\in A[X]$, we can check it in $A/(p)[X]$. But can we use Eisenstein criterion on $A/(p)$ ?

Comment: I computed a gcd in the non-PID ${\bf Z}[t]$, so I don't understand your first question. Your other questions should be posted as new questions. Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment, you have to put @Gerry in it.